# How to conditionally import and run a method from another Python package?

Tags: python

I have a project that contains several test suites. I want to be able to specify which suite I'd like to run in the command line:

```
suite=multiplication python3 .
```

Here's my current file structure:

```
__main__.py
suites/
    __init__.py
    addition.py
    subtraction.py
    multiplication.py
    division.py
```

**suites/__init__.py**

```
__all__ = ['addition', 'subtraction', 'multiplication', 'division']
```

**subtraction.py**

```
def testSuite():
    # Bunch of tests
```

**__main__.py**

```
import os
import suites

# Get suite name from 'suite=xxx' in command line
suiteName = os.getenv('suite')
# Based on suiteName, load the correct file
suite = suites[suiteName]
# Call the suite loaded from the file
suite()
```

This errors out:

```
suite = suites[suiteName]
TypeError: 'module' object is not subscriptable
```

What's the best way to conditionally import and run a script from another package?

Answer (score 4):

Use [`importlib.import_module`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.import_module):

```
from importlib import import_module

suite = import_module('suites.' + suiteName)
suite.testSuite()
```